# Decimal値をSQLServerに保存すると小数2桁までしか保存されない

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

- EntityFramework Version=6.0.0.0
- .Net Framework targetFramework="4.6.1"
- SQL Server Express 13.0.4001.0

SQL Server上のテーブルに、Decimal(12, 3)、Decimal(18, 3)で作成したカラムがあり、Linqを使ってそのカラムの更新を行っています。

```
decimal? d12 = 123.456m;
decimal? d18 = 222.222m;
Record rec = DbContext.Table.Where(a => a.id == 1).First();
rec.dec12_3col = d12;
rec.dec18_3col = d18;
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

そして更新後にSQL Server Management Studioでデータを確認すると、dec12_3colには 123.450、 dec18_3colには 222.220 が入っており、小数3桁めが切り捨てられてしまっています。

SaveChangesを呼び出す前のところでデバッガでrecを見てもそれぞれ小数3桁まで値がセットされているのを確認できるので、どこを直したらいいものなのか分からず困っています。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: DbContext.SaveChanges();実行前は期待した値が入っているのはご確認済みと考えていいでしょうか？またその他のdecimal以外の項目は更新できていますでしょうか？

Comment: デバッガの確認箇所の記載を追加しました

Answer (score 3):

DbContextに精度を記載することで解決できました。

```
public partial class ProjectDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Table>()
                .Property(e => e.dec12_3col)
                .HasPrecision(12, 3);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Table>()
                .Property(e => e.dec18_3col)
                .HasPrecision(18, 3);
    }
}
```

この修正で小数3桁めも正常にセットされるようになりました。

Comment: 精度の再定義前でも、デバッグ時の確認だと正常に値が入ってしまうように見えるんですね。勉強になりました。

Answer (score -2):

原因は何も配置しないとSQLのDecimalディフォルト精度(18,2)として使っていると思う。

プログラムの構成はわかりませんので、大体配置ファイルに下記のコード追加して改善かも。

```
<Property Name="dec12_3col" Type="decimal" Precision="12" Scale="3" Nullable="false" />
<Property Name="dec18_3col" Type="decimal" Precision="18" Scale="3" Nullable="false" />
```

Comment: すいません。何を追加したらいいのか分からないです。

Comment: @user25004 HTMLと誤解釈されてうまく表示されていない箇所があったので、回答に表示されるよう調整してみましたので確認してください。

Comment: あるいは、Recordクラスのプロパティ(dec18_3col)のヘッダで [DecimalPrecision(18, 3)]を追加するようにしてみて。

Comment: `DecimalPrecision` はサンプルコードの一部であり、クラスライブラリには存在しないかと。

Comment: @sayuri　ご指摘通り。